# How to give permissions to local computers using computers' MAC addresses in Windows Server 2016 for file sharing

Tags: authentication, windows-server-2016, file-permissions, file-sharing, mac-address

I have the following issue:

I have a server with Windows Server 2016, and I need to use it only for saving, reading, and modifying files with file sharing.

The way I have the restrictions is with logging in from client computers and logging with the local server accounts, but I need the authentication to be the MAC Addresses of the Computers clients which access to file sharing in order to be easy for the user.

Is there any way I can authenticate to access file sharing in the Windows Server with the client MAC address to give their respective permissions by MAC address from Windows Server?.

Comment: This is one of the things Active Directory is meant for, giving permissions by user.

Comment: Can i give permissions to Mac Address ??

Comment: Using MAC addressing for security just means you are fooling yourself that you have security. Security by MAC address is no security.

Comment: You know that MAC addresses are sniffable on the network, and settable by each host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to use the MAC address to designate share permissions but the short answer is no. MAC addresses can be spoofed so that wouldn't be a very secure setup. Anybody would be able to clone anyone else's MAC address to grant themselves access to another user's share.

You would use Active Directory Users and Computers to assign permissions on each share to either the user or machine. Also it's better to create groups/OUs and give the group permission to the file share. You would then add any user (or computer) who should have access to the file share to that group.